# UITableViewController overlapping the SearchBar of UISearchController in UIViewController in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am integrating `UISearchController` and `UITableViewController` in a `ViewController`.

Below is the code that I have implemented:

```
func configureSearchController() {

    let searchTableViewController = UITableViewController()

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchTableViewController)

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar
    self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Title"

    let searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar

    if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        textfield.textColor = UIColor.black
        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

            // Background color
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            // Rounded corner
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = false
        }
    }

    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    // Setting delegates and other stuff
    searchTableViewController.tableView.dataSource = self
    searchTableViewController.tableView.delegate = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self


    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
}
```

Now the problem is when I start typing in `SearchBar` the `TableViewController` is appearing over `SearchBar`.

How to add space between `SearchBar` and `TableViewController`?

This is how it looks :

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. I have tested your code, it is working totally fine. have you customized your navigation bar? as I can see , cancel button color is white instead of blue.

Comment: That is because I changed the `tintColor` of `NavigationBar` to white. Are you getting the space between `searchbar` and `tableview` ?

Comment: No. It totally works fine on my side.

Comment: Which xcode and swift version you are using? I created a sample and in that too same thing is happening.

Comment: Xcode 9.2 and test it in iPhone X simulator